# Noncompact complex manifolds admitting a semipositive holomorphic line bundle

Tags: complex-geometry

As well known, a compact complex manifold admitting a positive holomorphic line bundle is a **projective** manifold by Kodaira embedding. Furthermore, a compact complex manifold admitting a semipositive holomorphic line bundle which is positive somewhere is a **Moishezon** manifold by the Grauert-R conjecture.

**Qustion**: What are the behaviors or properties of a noncompact complex manifolds admitting a **semipositive / positive / quasi-positive** (semipositive everywhere and positive somewhere) holomorphic line bundle?
How many of these objects are there among all the noncompact manifolds?

Comment: On $\mathbb{C}^n$, and therefore on any Stein manifold, the trivial vector bundle (any rank) is positive...

Comment: @abx  Thank you. Can you tell us more general noncompact manifolds which admit a semipositive / positive / quasi-positive (semipositive everywhere and positive somewhere) holomorphic line bundle?  Better get rid of that class of manifolds which admit a strongly plurisubharmonic function (i.e. Stein manifolds), e.g. weakly pseudoconvex kahler manifolds.